# How can I check using PHP if URL already exists in database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, url, exists

I would like to be able to check using PHP a sql database for a url to see if it exists before inserting a new row in a table.

so if for example the data base has the following url already in it:
http://example.com

how do I query the data base to check if that URL already exists, or a url with that domain within it.

For example, if the domain http://example.com/directory/index.php is submitted i'd like that to return a match as the top level domain already exists.

Comment: The best way to do this depends on what your overall goal is with this check.  What are you trying to accomplish?  For example, it would be rather easy to make a new database table that parses your other table and adds a column of all the top-level domains (this is an example of a GOOD use of regex), and then you can just check that table.  Otherwise, CodeBird seems to have a useful solution

Comment: That's an interesting thought.  The primary reason is to ensure that if a domain exists, then I want to reject new submissions from a form that include the same domain to prevent multiple entries.

Comment: @Dave you're 100% right, but he doesn't really need regex, he can use `parse_url` on his DB entries, extract the top level domain out of them and store it in another column, it will actually make his life much easier in the in the future.

Comment: Then why is it important to reject the top-level domain?  isn't example.com/stuff1 different from example.com/stuff2 ?  I'd recommend storing URLs in their own table anyway.  That way you can reference them with the primary key of the table, rather than the record itself.  This is useful if you need to do changes to the URLs to clean up broken links, etc

Comment: yeah, good point @CodeBird, I was thinking of how he'd write the query in SQL, because I prefer to do most of my SQL administration directly in SQL and use php to interact with my model

Comment: Thanks guys.  Lots of food for thought.  Will take a look at this tonight when I can get access to my code and post back.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Something like this??? You can change your query depending on how all the URLs in the database are stored.

```
$url_parts=parse_url($url);
$domain=strtolower(str_replace('www.', '', $url_parts['host']));
$query=mysqli_query($dbconn, "SELECT column_name FROM table WHERE 
INSTR(LOWER(url_column_name), '$domain')");
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do a SELECT?

```
$url = 'http://example.com';

//Query using COUNT
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS num FROM `urls` WHERE `url` = :url";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':url', $url);
$stmt->execute();

$row  = $stmt->fetch();

if($row['num'] > 0){
    //URL already exists.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(REPLACE(URLfieldName, "http://", ""), "www.", ""), '/', 1) from tableName
```